# How to commit/push line feed (LF) into git repository

Tags: git

I have one file in my git repository with "CRLF" as end of line. when i click on "Show all Characters" in notepad++ , it will show "CRLF" end of every line. This file is tracked one , with below content.

```
{
"Inputs": {
     "General": [
           {
              "name": "test",
              "ID": "b"
           }]
         }
}
```

I have replaced this "CRLF" end of every line to "LF" using replace option in notepad++.

When i commit this change it is giving an error as below.

> nothing to commit, working tree clean
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)

How to commit this change in git.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be working on Windows, where the default line ending is CRLF.  Git, however, was developed on Linux, where the default line ending is LF; on Windows it defaults to translating CRLF into LF when text files are committed, and back from LF to CRLF when they are checked out.  There are no changes to be checked in because the file in the repository already has LF as its line ending.

This behavior is controlled by several different configuration parameters, but the main one is `core.autocrlf`.  On Linux this defaults to `input`; on Windows it defaults to `true`.  The behavior can be tuned (e.g. to specify which files should be treated as text) using a `.gitattributes` file in your repository.

See: [Dealing with line endings - GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-line-endings), "[Mind the End of Your
Line](https://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)" by
[Tim Clem](https://adaptivepatchwork.com/about/), and the man pages for `gitattributes` and `git-config`.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen , I have followed this [Dealing with line endings - GitHub Help](https://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)  , as it mentioned , i have added **.gitattribute** file with this text **_*.json text=input_**. I have committed then pushed this file into my repository, but still it displaying CRLF while cloning the repository.My git version is **2.14.1.windows.1** . I have added _core.autocrlf = input_ value as global git config property , but removed later as i am interested this change for specific repository only. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen , issue resolved. I have created **.gitattribute** file instead of creating **.gitattributes** file. Now i have created **.gitattributes** file and added this text **_*.json text eol=lf_** . Now the line feed is displaying with LF only.

Answer (score 3):

See [GitHub's article about dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).

Your Git is probably configured to transparently convert CRLFs to LFs or the other way around.